# if ListBox.SelectedIndex contains a number 1

Tags: c#, if-statement

Basically i'm trying to make it so if the Selected Index from a listbox (for example lets say the selected index is "Server1") contains a number ("1") or a certain word ("Server") it would do a certain thing. For example: If the selected index from the listbox contains a number 1, it would enter 1 into a text box. If the selected index contains a number 2, it would open up a application, just for an example.

what i tried:

```
        if (csrListBox.SelectedIndex = "1");
```

and:

```
        {
            List<string> items = ListBox.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
            foreach (string item in ListBox.Items)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"1");
                Match match = regex.Match(item);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    *Doing Something*
                }
            }

            ListBox.DataSource = items;
        }
```

Comment: `SelectedIndex`is an int. Try `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue`

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is an int, so use `if (csrListBox.SelectedIndex == 1){...}`. I assume you are not familiar with C# and normally using VB.NET. Always use the same type and use `==` instead of `=` if you want to compare.

Comment: The question is really unclear. Are you trying to execute your code if the **item at the selected** index contains "1" or a certain word? Or do you want to execute the code if the **selected index** itself is 1?

Comment: @louis if it contains "1" or a certain word

Comment: what is **it**, is it the **item** or the **index**? You seem to be using the 2 interchangeably, but the **index** has nothing to do with the **item/value** and both represent different things. In your rephrased question "Server1" is the **item**, we have no clue at what **index** in the listbox is this **item** and it doesn't seem to matter in the question you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
  if (csrListBox.SelectedIndex == 1);

The second "=" sign matters - it states you're doing a boolean check instead of assigning value "1" to the value.

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is a int index. Can`t be equal to "1"

Comment: Thanks, caught one mistake but not the other!

Answer (score 0):

Mistake - You are assigning value.

Use compare operator `==`. and SelectedIndex is `int` not string.

```
if (csrListBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    // Your code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you work with ListBox item values instead of selectedIndex as the SelectedIndex can only be an integer value. Something like this linq query will return if the ListBox contains a certain value that is selected. This takes care of multi-selections too.

```
var myValue = "1";
bool listContainsItem = ListBox.Items.Any(item => item.Value == myValue && item.Selected);
```